# Trend OfficeScan PowerShell or Batch Script

Tags: powershell, antivirus

I work for a healthcare provider as an analyst. We receive many CDs containing confidential patient data and one of my daily tasks is to scan the CD for viruses. I use Trend's OfficeScan tool for this and it does a great job but I would like to automate this process because there are a few other steps involved when it comes to these CDs such as scanning them for images and sending an email to the person who sent the CD. As the title suggests I'm attempting to create a script that will complete all these steps.

Here is my code so far

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Trend Micro\OfficeScan Client"
Start-Process ".\Wofielauncher.exe" "-manual_scan_target 'd:\'"
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\radiantviewer64bit\RadiAntViewer.exe" "-d 'd:\'"
```

The first two lines deal specifically with Trend's OfficeScan tool. The third is for a program called RadiAnt which scans the CDs for DICOM images.

The problem I'm having is I can't get the program to scan the right drive. As you can see I have the target drive set to D:\, but when I run the script it scans the C:\ instead.

Comment: Have you thought about exploring D: and copying its contents to some \temp location to be scanned? You also shouldn’t need to use Start-Process...just set your location and do cmd /c Wofielauncher.exe or just give the full path to the .exe without setting the location. It is just like running the exe native in cmd.

Comment: For example, at a Powershell console, typing c:\path\to\file.exe will launch the exe. No need to use Start-Process. It’s the same in ISE.

Comment: I would suspect that the program doesn't recognize a path `'d:\'` (note the single quotes) and falls back to C:\. Try `'-d "D:\"'` instead of `"-d 'D:\'"`.

Comment: I tried both suggestions, but neither one worked. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for the second line instead:

```
wofielauncher -manual_scan_target d:\
```